# Calculating average from ith element in list of tuples

Tags: python, python-3.x, tuples, average

Note: I've done edits to the dataset that I think will work better for calculating the average.

---

My data look like this:

```
[[2015, 0.23, 0.45, 1.23],
[2014, 1.22, 2.54, 0.98],
[2013, 0.33, 2.11, 0.43],
...]
```

Where the data are now lists within a list. The first element in the sublist is the year of growth, and the following three floats are the ring widths for that year. My question is this: Is there a way to calculate the average of the last three elements in each sublist, and generate a new list, with just year, average growth that would look something like:

```
[[2015, 1.58], [2014, 0.956], ...]
```

Where `1.58` is `(1.22 + 2.54 + 0.98)/3`.

Sorry for the confusion before, I'm new to Stack Overflow, and I can tell that more information is better.

Here is the code I have so far:

```
   for i in list[0]:
      newlist = [(list[1] + list[2] + list[3])/3]
```

But that doesn't seem to work.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Have you written some code already? In case you have, it would help, if you post it.

Comment: I added the code I have. Thank you for looking at this.

Comment: Hi @user2057916, welcome to StackOverflow! You should probably add the 'python' tag to your question so people can see at a glance that your question pertains to python.

Comment: Couldn't you just do  `tree1_list = [i[2] for i in trees if i[1]=='2015']`? And then do `sum()` divided by `len()`. Then, to get the other years, you just have to change 2015 to 2013, and then 2014.

Comment: I could definitely do that, but I have several hundred years of tree data.

Answer (score 3):

If your data is in the form:

```
trees= [[2015, 0.23, 0.45, 1.23],
        [2014, 1.22, 2.54, 0.98],
        [2013, 0.33, 2.11, 0.43]]
```

You could do:

```
new_trees=[]

for x in trees:
    average="{0:.2f}".format(sum(x[1:])/len(x[1:]))
    new_trees.append([x[0]]+[average])
                     #year + average
```

This would output:

```
>>> new_trees
[[2015, '0.64'], [2014, '1.58'], [2013, '0.96']]
```

Comment: Worked like a charm. Since my last post I had been working with the .append, but I had it in the wrong place. Thank you very much!

Comment: @user2057916 No problem! If my answer helped you, could you please consider check-marking it on the left? :) (I also included the 2 decimal place formatting like in your sample output)

Answer (score 0):

@logic has the first correct answer (should be the accepted answer), here's how to do it with a short list comprehension.

```
trees= [[2015, 0.23, 0.45, 1.23],
        [2014, 1.22, 2.54, 0.98],
        [2013, 0.33, 2.11, 0.43]]

data = [ (x[0], (sum(x[1:]) / len(x[1:])) ) for x in trees]
```

which yields this list of tuples:

```
[(2015, 0.6366666666666667), (2014, 1.58), (2013, 0.9566666666666667)]
```